# matplotlib dataframe x axis date issue

Tags: python, pandas

```
import sys
import ConfigParser
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as DT
import bokeh
sys.path.extend(['..\..\myProj\SOURCE'])

fullfilepath = "../../myProj/SOURCE/" + 'myparts.txt'
ohg_df = pd.read_csv(fullfilepath, sep="\t" )

temp_df = temp_df[['as_on_date', 'ohg_qty']]

temp_df = temp_df.sort(['as_on_date'], ascending=[1])

temp_df.set_index('as_on_date')

plt.plot(temp_df.index, temp_df.ohg_qty)

plt.show()
```

This is my dataframe after importing.

I am trying to plot the line graph with `x axis` as date mentioned in the dataframe.

Can someone guide me... I am new to pandas.

[dataframe picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fncjo.png)

[output pitcure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w15ak.png)

Comment: What problem do you have? Do you use `jupiter notebook` or smth alike?

Comment: either write
`temp_df = temp_df.set_index('as_on_date')`  or `temp_df.set_index('as_on_date', inplace=True)`

Comment: yes ..m using jupyter..but the in plot am not getting dateson x- axis...am getting index numbers

Answer (score 0):

Easier:

```
# Set index directly
ohg_df = pd.read_csv(fullfilepath, sep="\t", index='as_on_date')

# Convert string index to dates
ohg_df.index = pd.to_datetime(ohg_df.index)

# Get a column and plot it (taking a column keeps the index)
plt.plot(ohg_df.ohg_qty)
```

Comment: i am not getting dates on the x axis .....even after making as_on_date as index....am getting x axis as 100000, 200000, 300000

Comment: have added outputpicture in the question , at the bottom

Comment: have added output picture at the bottom of the question

Comment: what are the values in `as_on_date`

Comment: your solution ..has removed the index and has made new to 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000557641.....1970-01-01 00:00:00.000463113..so on

Comment: index  ,  as_on_date ,  ohg_qty
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000557641  , 2016-11-13, 39404.0

Comment: `temp_df['as_on_date'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_df['as_on_date'])`        
`temp_df = temp_df.set_index('as_on_date')`